# SQL - Only include rows that have more than one in class

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to eliminate classes with only 1 pupil

Here is the result i have

[image: Result]

Desired Result

[image]

I want only class c to show as it has more than one pupil

I believe its some way of using HAVING but i cant figure it out.

```
SELECT Pupil, class
FROM school
```

Comment: That table makes very little sense however I try and think about it

Comment: And is this a MYSQL or SQLServer question

Comment: class "a" also has more than one pupil.  are you wanting 4 records instead of 2?

Comment: SQL Server. Also its a small subset of a larger result. I thought i explained it correctly.

Comment: @Ryan Class A has only pupil 2 so therefore has only 1 pupil

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: why are there duplicate rows for classes a and b? Is the source data faulty? Surely a pupil can't be in the same class twice. Or are there some other fields which vary, which you haven't shown?

Answer (score 5):

Using `IN`

```
select * 
from school
where class in (select class 
                from school 
                group by class 
                having count(distinct Pupil) > 1)
```